# Use action, filter, or hook to append HTML to WordPress plugin function

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am new to WordPress actions, filters, and hooks, and am wondering if it is possible to use one of the three to append some HTML to a defined plugin function using the theme's functions.php file. The HTML is helper text that is currently in the plugin's main PHP file, but would I like to move it to the functions.php file because of future updates to the plugin. The paragraph with the class of "appended-text" is what should be appended to the HTML using an action, filter, or hook.

Plugin's function:

```
public function insert_upload_form() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) ) {
        return; //Users must be author or greater
    }

$user_id = $this->get_user_id();
$post_id = $this->get_post_id( $user_id );

?>
<tr valign="top" class="user-metronet-profile-picture">
    <th scope="row"><?php esc_html_e( 'Profile Image', 'metronet-profile-picture' ); ?></th>
    <td id="mpp">
        <input type="hidden" name="metronet_profile_id" id="metronet_profile_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user_id ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="metronet_post_id" id="metronet_post_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post_id ); ?>" />
        <div id="metronet-profile-image">
        <?php
        $has_profile_image = false;
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) {
            $has_profile_image = true;
            echo '<a style="display:block" href="#" class="mpp_add_media">';
            $thumb_src      = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'thumbnail', false, '' );
            $post_thumbnail = sprintf( '<img style="display:block" src="%s" width="150" height="150" title="%s" />', esc_url( $thumb_src[0] ), esc_attr__( 'Upload or Change Profile Picture', 'metronet-profile-picture' ) );
            echo wp_kses_post( $post_thumbnail );
            echo sprintf( '<div id="metronet-click-edit">%s</div>', esc_html__( 'Click to Edit', 'metronet-profile-picture' ) );
            echo '</a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a style="display:block" href="#" class="mpp_add_media default-image">';
            $post_thumbnail = sprintf( '<img style="display:block" src="%s" width="150" height="150" title="%s" />', self::get_plugin_url( 'img/mystery.png' ), esc_attr__( 'Upload or Change Profile Picture', 'metronet-profile-picture' ) );
            echo wp_kses_post( $post_thumbnail );
            echo sprintf( '<div id="metronet-click-edit">%s</div>', esc_html__( 'Click to Edit', 'metronet-profile-picture' ) );
            echo '</a>';
        }
        $remove_classes = array( 'dashicons', 'dashicons-trash' );
        if ( ! $has_profile_image ) {
            $remove_classes[] = 'mpp-no-profile-image';
        }
        ?>
            <a id="metronet-remove" class="<?php echo implode( ' ', $remove_classes ); // phpcs:ignore ?>" href="#" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Remove profile image', 'metronet-profile-picture' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Remove profile image', 'metronet-profile-picture' ); ?></a>
            <div style="display: none">
                <?php printf( '<img class="mpp-loading" width="150" height="150" alt="Loading" src="%s" />', esc_url( self::get_plugin_url( '/img/loading.gif' ) ) ); ?>
            </div>
        </div><!-- #metronet-profile-image -->
        <div id="metronet-override-avatar">
            <input type="hidden" name="metronet-user-avatar" value="off" />
            <?php
            //Get the user avatar override option - If not set, see if there's a filter override.
            $user_avatar_override = get_user_option( 'metronet_avatar_override', $user_id );
            $checked = '';
            if ( $user_avatar_override ) {
                $checked = checked( 'on', $user_avatar_override, false );
            } else {
                $checked = checked( true, apply_filters( 'mpp_avatar_override', false ), false );
            }

            //Filter for hiding the override interface.  If this option is set to true, the mpp_avatar_override filter is ignored and override is enabled by default
            $hide_override = apply_filters( 'mpp_hide_avatar_override', false );
            if ( $hide_override ) :
                ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="metronet-user-avatar" id="metronet-user-avatar" value="on"  />
                <?php
                else :
                    ?>
                    <br /><input type="checkbox" name="metronet-user-avatar" id="metronet-user-avatar" value="on" <?php echo $checked; // phpcs:ignore ?> /> <label for="metronet-user-avatar"><?php esc_html_e( 'Override Avatar?', 'metronet-profile-picture' ); ?></label>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- #metronet-override-avatar -->
        <p class="appended-text">
            <strong>Note: optimum image size is 200 pixels wide by 200 pixels tall.<br>
            Maximum file size is 200KB.<br>
            (Your profile image may appear "squished" in this preview, but will appear normal on articles and events you post, and on your author page.)
            </strong>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
/**
 * Allow other plugins to run code after the user profile picture UI.
 *
 * @since 2.3.0
 *
 */
do_action( 'mpp_user_profile_form', $user_id );
} //end insert_upload_form
```

Answer (score -1):

plugin Function

```
function printed_content(){
return '<p>html to render</p>';
}
```

Theme function.php

```
$data = printed_content();
echo $data;
```

Comment: This solution does not apply to this problem. The plugin's function needs to be modified using an action, filter, or hook in the theme's functions file.

Comment: Do you mean you want to call your plugin function from function.php of a theme?

Comment: I want to append the paragraph text to the HTML output generated by the public function in the plugin using my theme's functions file. Currently this is being achieved directly in the plugin, which is not ideal.

Comment: If you return the html from plugin function like my answer above you will call that function in your function.php file like -> $data = printed_content(); and now $data will contain your plugin function html